# TXT DE EXTRATO BANCARIO (LANCAMENTOS)

Tags: python, txt, dataframe

Galera, bom dia.

Estou com o seguinte problema.

Tenho uns arquivos tipo txt de extratos bancarios no qual eu preciso jogar para um dataframe, eles até que tem um layout meio padrao. Eu preciso pegar somente as linhas dos lançamentos contábeis(linhas que tem dt.movimento o resto pode desconsiderar), tentei um pouco aqui e até consegui pegar as linhas com o comando line.split('\t') porém eles não são separados por tabulação(TAB)

Gostaria de saber se alguem consegue me ajudar com esse problema.

(Exemplo Extrato Bancario)
[image: Exemplo Extrato Bancario]

ARQUIVO TXT

```html
================================================================================================================================================================
Extrato conta corrente                                                                                                                       5152152141421124144
                                                                                                                                             11/12/2018 15:57:30
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cliente - Cliente atual
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Agência                       3214-1
Conta corrente                2341-1 XPTO ENTERPRISE
Período do extrato            
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Lançamentos
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Dt. movimento  Dt. balancete    Ag. origem        Lote     Histórico                                    Documento         Valor R$            Saldo
   29/11/2018                       0000          00000     000 Saldo Anterior                                                            9.104,88 C
   05/12/2018                       0000          13113     435 Tarifa Pacote de Serviços      432.432424.24234.43         128,00 D       8.976,88 C
                              Tarifa referente a 05/12/2018
   10/12/2018                       0000          14175     976 TED-Crédito em Conta                     7.962.643      15.000,00 C      23.976,88 C
                              341 0192 56998438000165 EMPRESA ABC
   10/12/2018                       0000          13013     364 BB Consórcio - Prestação                    12.068       1.264,91 D      22.711,97 C
   10/12/2018                       0000          13013     364 BB Consórcio - Prestação                    23.068       1.264,90 D      21.447,07 C
   10/12/2018                       0000          13013     364 BB Consórcio - Prestação                    23.068       1.264,91 D      20.182,16 C
   10/12/2018                       0000          13013     364 BB Consórcio - Prestação                    51.068       1.264,91 D      18.917,25 C
   10/12/2018                       0000          13013     364 BB Consórcio - Prestação                    21.068       1.264,91 D      17.652,34 C
   10/12/2018                       0000          13013     364 BB Consórcio - Prestação                   543.068       1.264,91 D       16.387,43 C
   10/12/2018                       0000          13013     364 BB Consórcio - Prestação                    23.068       1.264,91 D      15.122,52 C
   10/12/2018                       0000          13013     364 BB Consórcio - Prestação                    31.068       1.264,91 D      13.857,61 C
   10/12/2018                       0000          13013     364 BB Consórcio - Prestação                    74.068       1.264,91 D      12.592,70 C
   10/12/2018                       0000          13013     364 BB Consórcio - Prestação                    23.068       1.264,91 D      11.327,79 C
   10/12/2018                       0000          13013     364 BB Consórcio - Prestação                    61.068       1.264,91 D      10.062,88 C
   10/12/2018                       0000          13013     364 BB Consórcio - Prestação                    23.068       1.264,91 D       8.797,97 C
   11/12/2018                       0000          00000     999 S A L D O                                                8.797,97 C       8.797,97 C
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Saldo                                                                 8.797,97 C
Juros                                                                       0,00
Data de Debito de Juros                                               31/12/2018
IOF                                                                         0,00
Data de Debito de IOF                                                 02/01/2019
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
               ------------------------------------------------
               ------------------------------------------------
               OBSERVAÇÕES:
               ------------------------------------------------
               
               

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Transação efetuada com sucesso por: 234252 GENESIO MARINHO
```

Comment: A maioria dos bancos no Brasil, se não todos, oferecem os extratos no formato `.ofx` (Open Financial Exchange), o melhor caminho é voce baixar nesse formato e usar uma ferramenta apropriada para extrair as informacoes, por exemplo a [ofxtools](https://github.com/csingley/ofxtools).

Comment: Aliás... O formato `ofx` é uma m#rda (uma expecie de xml ainda mais macorronico) mas é o padrão dos bancos (talvez imposto pelo padrão de dados do Quiken), e já que teve uma "boa alma" para fazer um parse para o python, pq não aproveita-lo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que as colunas são fixas. Crie um dicionário com as posições de cada campo dentro da linha:

```
coordenadas = {
    'dt_movimento': (3, 13),
    'dt_balancete': (18, 28),
    'ag_origem': (36, 40),
    'lote': (50, 55),
    'cod_historico': (60, 63),
    'historico': (64, 100),
    'documento': (101, 114),
    'valor': (115, 129),
    'valor_dc': (130, 131),
    'saldo': (132, 146),
    'saldo_dc': (147, 148),
}
```

Aí fica fácil, é só dividir cada linha e gerar um registro:

```
with open('extrato.txt') as f:
    df = pd.DataFrame({nome_campo: linha[inicio:fim] 
        for nome_campo, (inicio, fim) in coordenadas.items()}
        for linha in f
        if linha[5:6] == '/')
```

O critério usado aqui é a barra `/` da data na quinta posição.